# Is $\liminf \limsup$ always greater than or equal to $\limsup \liminf$?

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Lets say we have a function $f:X \times Y \to \mathbb R$. Is it always true that

$$ \liminf_{y \to b} \limsup_{x \to a} f(x,y) \geq \limsup_{x \to a} \liminf_{y \to b} f(x,y)$$
?

This question was inspired by the fact that we always have 
$$\inf_{y \in Y} \sup_{x \in X} f(x,y) \geq \sup_{x \in X} \inf_{y \in Y}f(x,y)$$

I have been trying to use the latter to prove the former, but have had no success, so I am starting to doubt whether or not it is true. Can someone shed some insight?

Comment: Think about the relationship between sup and limsup and inf and liminf

Comment: @RhythmInk I have been doing quite a bit of that. In fact, you can write $\liminf_{x \to a}$ as $\sup_{r > 0} \inf_{|x-a|<r}$ and likewise with sup... things just don't seem to be working out nicely though.

Comment: How does sup$(a_n)$ compare to limsup$(a_n)$

Comment: @RhythmInk it is always greater, I believe.

Comment: Yep. What about for inf and liminf?

Comment: I see what you're saying, if I try to follow that line of reasoning, I get: $ \liminf \limsup \geq \liminf \sup \geq \sup \liminf \geq \limsup \liminf$?

Comment: @RhythmInk It turns out this statement is not true. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is false. Consider $f(x,y)=[x>y]$ and $a=b=\infty$.